# Mark the regions over the zed graph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Currently I am using ZedGraph to display my curve. I want to mark the particular regions of the curve over the ZedGraph control and label it like follows.

[image]

Note: I need different type of markings in the X and Y axis based on the text size.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options,

1) Use [BoxObject](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_BoxObj.htm) to draw at a specific region as follows

[image]

and you can use the source code as follows:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of Graph Pane
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        // Build a PointPairList with points based on Sine wave
        PointPairList list = new PointPairList();
        for (double i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            double x = i * 10.0 + 50.0;
            double y = Math.Sin(i * Math.PI / 15.0) * 16.0;
            list.Add(x, y);
        }

        // Hide the legend
        myPane.Legend.IsVisible = false;

        // Add a curve
        LineItem curve = myPane.AddCurve("label", list, Color.Red, SymbolType.Circle);
        curve.Line.Width = 1.5F;
        curve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill(Color.White);
        curve.Symbol.Size = 5;

        // Make the XAxis start with the first label at 50
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.BaseTic = 50;

        // Fill the axis background with a gradient
        myPane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.SteelBlue, 45.0F); 

        // Draw Region 1
        drawRegion(list[0].X, list[10].X,"Positive Cycle");

        // Calculate the Axis Scale Ranges
        zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();

        // Refresh to paint the graph components
        Refresh(); 
    }

    private void drawRegion(double xMin, double xMax, string regName)
    {
        GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        BoxObj box = new BoxObj(xMin,20, xMax, 40.0, Color.Empty, Color.LightSteelBlue);// Color.FromArgb(225, 245, 225));
        box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
        box.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Left;
        box.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Top;

        // place the box behind the axis items, so the grid is drawn on top of it
        box.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindCurves;//.D_BehindAxis;//.E_BehindAxis;
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(box);

        // Add Region text inside the box 
        TextObj myText = new TextObj(regName, 160, -15);
        myText.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
        myText.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
        myText.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Center;
        myText.FontSpec.IsItalic = true;
        myText.FontSpec.IsBold = false;
        myText.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Red;
        myText.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = false;
        myText.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(myText);

        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

2) This is a bit difficult but do-able, Draw individual vertical lines discussed here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002252/zedgraph-adding-threshold-line), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422398/drawing-line-on-a-click-on-zedgraph-pane) and add the required text etc.

I suggest you to use the `option 1`, which is lot easier than 2 !

Comment: Thanks for your response San. My requirement team is not okay with your alternate solution. I think, currently no other graph is also supports these type of markings in graph. So, I started to write my own control to do this. Thanks again for your help.